# How to get the full row of data based on max value?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have an Oracle table with a usage counter.  I need to get the full row of data for each sensor with the max counter value?

For ALO I need data in row 2.
For AMA I need data in row 10.
For A11 I need data in row 9658.
For MSP I need data in row 9659.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: My bad, For A11 I need row 20 and for MSP row 21.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots  but text.

Comment: What result is appropriate when multiple counters are of identical value for a given sensor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window function.

```
selcet * from (
  select a.*, row_number() over (partition by facility_id_n
      order by usage_counter_n desc) rn
  from your_tbl a) 
where rn =1;
```

Or use the First window-funcrion.

Answer (score 0):

ROW_NUMBER won't return correct result if there are two rows with the same USAGE_COUNTER_N value per FACILITY_ID_N. For example:

```
SQL> WITH test
  2       AS (SELECT 9640 ID_n, 'ALO' sensor_id_c, 317 usage_counter_n FROM DUAL
  3           UNION
  4           SELECT 9641, 'ALO', 18 FROM DUAL
  5           UNION
  6           SELECT 9642, 'ALO', 0 FROM DUAL
  7           UNION
  8           SELECT 9659, 'MSP', 25 FROM DUAL --> MAX for MSP ...
  9           UNION
 10           SELECT 9660, 'MSP', 10 FROM DUAL
 11           UNION
 12           SELECT 1000, 'MSP', 25 FROM DUAL --> ... but this is also MAX for MSP
 13          )
 14  SELECT *
 15    FROM (SELECT a.*,
 16                 ROW_NUMBER ()
 17                 OVER (PARTITION BY sensor_id_c
 18                       ORDER BY usage_counter_n DESC) rn
 19            FROM test a)
 20   WHERE rn = 1;

      ID_N SEN USAGE_COUNTER_N         RN
---------- --- --------------- ----------
      9640 ALO             317          1
      1000 MSP              25          1

SQL>
```

RANK might be better:

```
SQL> l16
 16*                ROW_NUMBER ()
SQL> c/row_number/rank
 16*                rank ()
SQL> /

      ID_N SEN USAGE_COUNTER_N         RN
---------- --- --------------- ----------
      9640 ALO             317          1
      1000 MSP              25          1
      9659 MSP              25          1

SQL>
```

Or, using the oldfashioned way:

```
 14    SELECT *
 15      FROM test t
 16     WHERE t.usage_counter_n = (SELECT MAX (t1.usage_counter_n)
 17                                  FROM test t1
 18                                 WHERE t1.sensor_id_c = t.sensor_id_c)
 19  ORDER BY sensor_id_c;

      ID_N SEN USAGE_COUNTER_N
---------- --- ---------------
      9640 ALO             317
      9659 MSP              25
      1000 MSP              25

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements to handle duplicates, the KEEP clause might also be a useful option

```
SQL> with test
  2       AS (SELECT 9640 ID_n, 'ALO' sensor_id_c, 317 usage_counter_n FROM DUAL
  3           UNION
  4           SELECT 9641, 'ALO', 18 FROM DUAL
  5           UNION
  6           SELECT 9642, 'ALO', 0 FROM DUAL
  7           UNION
  8           SELECT 9659, 'MSP', 25 FROM DUAL --> MAX for MSP ...
  9           UNION
 10           SELECT 9660, 'MSP', 10 FROM DUAL
 11           UNION
 12           SELECT 1000, 'MSP', 25 FROM DUAL --> ... but this is also MAX for MSP
 13          )
 14  SELECT sensor_id_c,
 15         min(id_n) keep ( dense_rank first order by usage_counter_n DESC ) id_n,
 16         min(usage_counter_n) keep ( dense_rank first order by usage_counter_n DESC ) usage_counter_n
 17  from test
 18  group by sensor_id_c;

SEN       ID_N USAGE_COUNTER_N
--- ---------- ---------------
ALO       9640             317
MSP       1000              25
```